# Genre or similar songs to this proprietary track

Tags: identify-this-genre, guitar

I recently stumbled upon a video from which I extracted a proprietary song whose artist/name were kept secret. However, I really want to know where I can find more of this genre, that I would classify as some kind of vintage blues rock, because of those slowed-down overdriven guitar strums and solo. It reminds me of this surf-rock era depicted in some movies such as Pulp Fiction, but I feel this is yet another genre as it is way slower and vibrant.

Any artist/band name similar to this ?

Links: [**This**](https://youtu.be/1SjYhic9fpg) is the software-extracted version of the song from the [**original video**](https://youtu.be/ASSWJDsDfZM?t=1m), where it appears at 1:00

Comment: Well, I usually don't like (and I'm also not able) to identify genre, but this kind of sound reminds me [Chris Isaak's *Wicked Game*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5D3Nl1GZzuw), you should try to dig on this side.

Comment: It sounds like a cover of a surf-rock song: kind of like Centurions Bullwinkle/Bullwinkle 2, but the recording equipment is "too good." I am abut 95% certain this is used in a movie soundtrack (non-Tarantino).

Comment: It has hints of Albatros, early Fleetwood Mac too - try "early R&B" & don't get confused with that c**p they call R&B these days, which has nothing to do with it.

Comment: sounds like a post-/surf rock to me, also reminds Neil Young's passages from "Dead man" soundtrack and a bit of Friends of Dean Martinez

Answer (score 1):

Like comments have written, it sounds a lot like post rock.

For one example try this one: [We Lost The Sea - The Last Dive of David Shaw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4yEo-TXfBQ).
Go to 3 minute mark to skip the intro.